# Can't reference .NET in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to implement some Speech Recognition stuff in a Visual Studio project, but am having trouble.  To do this I need to reference Windows .NET, but am not able to.  When I open the Add Reference menu, there aren't any options there.  There is no .NET tab.  I know that I have downloaded .NET, because when I try to download it again it tells me that I already have it installed.  However, I can't figure out where on my computer it is, or why Visual Studio won't recognize it.

Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Comment: What project type are you working with?

Comment: A project for a Spoken Dialogue Systems class.  This isn't a problem with the project itself, though--I just want to be able to add .NET as a reference using Visual Studio.  I feel like that shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Are you using a native C++ project or something?

Comment: Yeah, I just created a New Project and chose to make it a Console Application.  All the automatically generated stuff is C++.

Comment: Well .NET and C++ are usually mutually exclusive. There's Managed C++ (deprecated) and C++/CLI that will bridge .NET and C++ together. Or you can [host the CLR in C++](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=host+clr+in+c%2B%2B) but for convenience you probably want to use something other than C++.